# Maintaining API tokens for the entire server in PHP web application

Tags: php, web-applications

I am developing a PHP application which uses a web service in the back end. To use this web service first the web application should provide a username and password and get an API token which will be valid only for some time. When users logged into the PHP application they will use this back end service and for that the server should user API token that it got previously. This API token is not per user but for the entire application. The PHP web application also needs to periodically update this Token. What is the best approach to maintain this token in server side and periodically update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were not a lot of details in your question, but I am getting a feeling that you want to build an OAuth server as the backend service. There's an amazing package that does this: [OAuth-Server](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server).

If you are new to OAuth, you may want to read about it [here](http://blog.varonis.com/introduction-to-oauth/). To give you perspective, when you allow some Facebook app to access your account details, the OAuth server generates an token for your account and passes it to the app to access your account. Although, facebook has per-user tokens, you can create per-app tokens too (it is called 'Client Credentials Grant' in OAuth terms).

Comment: Thanks Mohit. But can you tell me what is the best way to maintain this API token in the server. How can I create a shared variable that every thread can access.

Comment: You can put the token in a common storage like on the DB server or if you want to keep it in-memory, programs like Redis can be useful.